# Rails: multiple submit button outside simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Say I have an Article model, and in the Article model 'settings' view I have two submit buttons outside of a form, "update Details" and "Next Template".

My question is **how can I know which button is clicked in the controller**. Both submit button is outside of a simple form. 
I tried like:

```
 <%= f.submit "update Details",name: "update_details", class: "x-update" %>


<%= f.submit 'Next Template', name: "next_template", class: "x-next" %>
```

and the logic is the same on the controller

```
   if params[:update_details]
      [..]
   elsif params[:next_template]
      [..]
   end
```

but it doesn't work. How do I do that? I can't change the route, so is there a way to send a different variable that gets picked up by [:params]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by putting in our html form template:

```
<input type="hidden" name= "action_type" id="action_type">
```

then in JavaScript file we added

```
$('.x-update').on 'click', ->
$("#action_type").val("exit")
$("#details-form").submit()
```

and then in controller file we checked the parameters:

```
if params[:action_type] == "exit"
  redirect_to #your desired path
else
  redirect_to #based on given path
```

That's It. It works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this:

```
<%= f.submit "update Details",name: "update_details", value: true, class: "x-update" %>
<%= f.submit 'Next Template', name: "next_template", value: true, class: "x-next" %>
```

Optionally, I think you can use same names, and different values.

```
<%= f.submit "update Details",name: "next_template", value: false,  class: "x-update" %>
<%= f.submit 'Next Template', name: "next_template", value: true, class: "x-next" %>
```

And in the controller:

```
if params[:next_template]
  something
else
  something_else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in the controller to check, what params you getting when trigging the submit.

```
render plain: params
```

Additional You can use "hidden_field_tag" option in side a form.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'plan', params[:plan] = 2 %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to put both buttons inside form and then try with same logic.